# adjustbox doesn't allow line breaks in enumerate environment. How to fix that?

Tags: lists, line-breaking, enumerate, adjustbox

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{hello\\world}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

For a MWE. How to allow the line break as expected?

Another MWE for better comprehension:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \adjustbox{valign=t}{$\begin{aligned}
        x^2 - y^2 & = x^2 - xy + xy - y^2 \\
        & = (x+y)(x-y)\\
    \end{aligned}$\\world}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `minipage =x cm` option, like `\adjustbox{valign=t, minipage=6cm}{...}`

Comment: Never use `\adjustbox` for text. It leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: @Bernard if he uses it just for the `align` key I guess it's fine.

Comment: @Skillmon: Maybe, but it is simpler to use `$\begin{aligned}[t] …`

Comment: @Bernard I sought a solution to misaligned enumerate environment numberings and `\adjustbox` seems to be the solution I got.

Comment: @BookOfFlames: if it is for multilined equations, use the [t] optional argument, as I said.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, it works for equations as you say, but for pictures like `tikzpicture` I think `adjustbox` is the way ...

Comment: @Bernard You add an answer, Bernard.

Comment: @Skillmon: no worry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow line breaks you can use the `minipage=` option of the adjustbox environment (see chapter 4.12 on p. 44 of the manual).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox, amsmath, graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \adjustbox{valign=t, minipage=4.3cm}{
                $\begin{aligned}
                    x^2 - y^2 & = x^2 - xy + xy - y^2 \\
                              & = (x+y)(x-y)\\
                \end{aligned}$\\
                
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} % has the width of the minipage (here 4.3cm) 
            \\
            hello, \\
            world
            }
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, it is enough to use the `[t]` placement option of the `aligned` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
        x^2 - y^2 & = x^2 - xy + xy - y^2 \\
        & = (x+y)(x-y)\\
    \end{aligned}$\\world
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it answers the original question, but please don't remove your answer, it is a valuable resource.